# How can I transfer custom tokens(USDT, BNB etc) on Ethereum Chain using Walletconnect and ethers.js?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, ethers.js, wallet-connect

I am trying to transfer custom tokens on Ethereum chain using ethers.js with walletconnect as provider. I can successfully transfer ETH but when I try to transfer any other token using contract address, the dialog in trust wallet which I have connected to walletconnect always shows ETH as the transfering currency.

I have done the following implementation and I can't figure out where the issue is.

```
        const web3 = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereumProvider);
        const signer = web3.getSigner();
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(
          contractAdderss,
          ABI,
          signer
        );
        const transfer = await contract.transfer(
          walletAddress,
          ethers.utils.parseUnits(amount)
        );
```

Comment: Its unclear what the contract abi is, is it an ERC-20?   The flow here looks weird as well.  Why are you trying to transfer erc-20 tokens to a contract, why aren't you calling approve, and then calling the method on the contract which consumes the tokens

Comment: Yes ERC-20 tokens, got the ABI and contract address from Ethereum explorer. I am creating an application which uses multiple wallets to transfer tokens. I am having issue with walletconnect currently. I approve the connection using walletconnector provider, by scanning the QR code. Then for transferring tokens, I want to invoke the transfer function of the respective contract for Ethereum chain.

Comment: "approve the connection using walletconnector provider"  that sounds like you're just connecting, you need to approve spending the tokens and pull them from the contract, alternatively you can push but then theres no good way of tracking

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72800889/how-to-automate-usdt-sending-transactions